# Any type of bluetooth code, even without errors, causes a force close on any Android Version

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, forceclose

I have tried using the code from the bluetooth chat example and sending a string. I have tried using the bluetooth code from [YAALL - the LEDs flash another Arduino(translated)](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/viewtopic.php?p=10970239)
I have tried using the code from [Bluetooth Steering Wheel](http://www.karelbruneel.com/blog/2011/01/steering-wheel/). With no bluetooth code, my app works fine, my debugging code at the bottom successfully updates with all of the correct values, in the correct format as it should be sent, and as it should be received by my electronics boards. As soon as I add in any kind of bluetooth code, with no errors, without even trying to send anything, my app force closes on Open/Launch.

So my code is extensive, so I shall post it on pastebin with the following links(pastebin DOT com SLASH [the random characters]

MainActivity.java 1T3MfMwE

BluetoothSPPConnection.java ZqhxK2ZL

BluetoothSPPConnectionListener.java mkZcXRFx

ColorPickerDialog.java JywFkBDX

DeviceListActivity.java 0kEQzF1G

Comment: Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not include bluetooth permissions. That was all.